# Exclude duplicates returns in MySQLi Select / Like searches

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm learning a bunch in the last few days, but figuring out how to exclude duplicate records has me just boggled...

http://1KaraokeDJ.com

Search "abba" using Title Search button
2 results returned

notice it's a duplicate just on a different Disc.

How do I just show the first found?
This is just 1 example: there are 100s of duplicates and it's normal. They are just different Disc Sets. However, Sound Choice and DKKaraoke are different recording labels and are not a duplicate. So only duplicate if Disc ID starts with same code - ie DK088 and DK056 are a dupe but DK088 and SC5101 are not a dupe if same artist and title... or compare Brand may be easier.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
  ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',900);
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',900);
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['searchbtn'])) { $_SESSION['searchterm']=$_POST['searchterm']; }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>1KaraokeDJ.com Search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="post">
        <p><code>
          <img src="top1.jpg" /><br>
          <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo("Mobile Device Detected"); } else { echo("Desktop Browser Detected"); } ?>
        </code></p>
        <p>
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['searchterm'])) { ?>
            <input name="searchterm" type="search" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['searchterm'];?>" class="search" />
          <?php } else { ?>
            <input name="searchterm" type="search" placeholder="Enter Search Terms Here"  class="search" />
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input name="searchbtn" type="submit" id="searchbtn" class="hiddenbutton" value="Karaoke Search" />
          <input name="searchbtn" type="submit" id="searchbtn" class="searchbutton" value="Artist Search"  />
          <input name="searchbtn" type="submit" id="searchbtn" class="searchbutton" value="Title Search"  />
          <input name="searchbtn" type="submit" id="searchbtn" class="searchbutton" value="Disc ID Search"  />
        </p>
        <hr style="width:100%">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['searchterm'])) {
          if(($_SESSION['searchterm']!="")) {
            $searchterm=strtoupper($_SESSION['searchterm']);
            switch ($_POST['searchbtn']) {
              case 'Karaoke Search':
                $searchresults=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where Artist like '%$searchterm%' || Title like '%$searchterm%' || Disc like '%$searchterm%' order by Artist, Title limit 100");
                break;
              case 'Artist Search':
                $searchresults=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where Artist like '%$searchterm%' order by Title, Disc limit 100");
                break;
              case 'Title Search':
                $searchresults=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' order by Artist, Disc limit 100");
                break;
              case 'Disc ID Search':
                $searchresults=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where Disc like '%$searchterm%' limit 100");
                break;
            }           
            if(mysqli_num_rows($searchresults) > 0) {
              while($descri=mysqli_fetch_object($searchresults)) { ?>
                <div class="reslt">
                  <h3 id="results">
                    <?php
                      echo str_ireplace($searchterm, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchterm."</span>", $descri->Artist);
                      echo " - ";
                      echo str_ireplace($searchterm, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchterm."</span>", $descri->Title);
                    ?>
                  </h3>
                  <p class="Description">
                    <?php
                      echo $descri->Brand; echo " - ";
                      echo str_ireplace($searchterm, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchterm."</span>", $descri->Disc);
                      echo " - "; echo $descri->Track;
                    ?>
                  </p>
                  <hr>
                </div>
              <?php } ?>
            <div class="reslt">
              <h3 id="results"><?php echo mysqli_num_rows($searchresults) ?> Results</h3>
              <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($searchresults) >= 100) { ?>
                <p class="Description highlight">Showing Up To 100 Results<br>Try Refining Your Search</p>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          <?php   } else { ?>
            <div class="reslt">
              <h3 id="results">Nothing Found!</h3>
              <p class="Description highlight">Try Changing Your Search Terms<p>
              <?php if ($_POST['searchbtn'] == "Disc ID Search" ) { ?>
                Chartbuster = CBxxx<br>
                DKKaraoke = DKxxx<br>
                Karaoke Hits = KHxxx<br>
                Sound Choice = SCxxx<br>
                Sunfly = SFxxx
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          <?php }
        } } ?>
      </form>
      <hr>
      <code>&copy; D &amp; C Entertainment 2003 - 2015</code>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not meant to be an ad... Just didn't know a better way to give my example. I'm trying to learn how to build my own site search database

Comment: My apologies...I thought this was a spam.  Upvoted your question.

Comment: The examples I've seen use JavaScript or other libraries, I'm trying to only use php and MySQLi. Plus I'm really just learning and I've spent days and days just learning basic how to stuff. Now I'm into the meat of a searching... I've noticed you can do selects within selects and it's just got me confused.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
SELECT DISTINCT discId FROM youTable WHERE itMatchsYourField ORDER BY artist
```

This will only return you unique discId

So you wont end up with twice the same DK. Now in your exemble you have 2 DKXXX

Since only the 2 first letter mathers you should use something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(discId , 2) FROM yourTable
```

This way you il not get twice DK you will get SC or DK and the first one that comes up

Comment: 'Select DISTINCT Brand from 1KaraokeDJ where Artist like '%$searchterm%' || Title like '%$searchterm%' order by Artist, Title limit 100 '  - only returns 1 of each Brand and not the rest of the record set. See above website and hit test button...

Comment: Ok so you search for Abba and you want all Title but only once per record set? is that corect? If it is then you need to do a distinct on the title and the discId field. so you could get the same song twice only if the are from SC or DK.

Comment: Database looks like this: ID, Disc, Track, Artist, Title, Brand. ID is unique primary key, Disc/Artist/Title varchar and Brand is 1 of 6 values. So search for Title "abba" returns 2 records from same Brand. This is an unwanted dupe... If from different Brands then not a dupe.

Comment: And how do I retrieve the rest of the data? Select distinct only returns the values requested - I need all the data - select *

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after doing more research... It seems I need to use a inner join?

```
select DISTINCT ID, Title, Brand from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' AS temp
select * from 1KaraokeDJ inner join temp on 1KaraokeDJ.ID=temp.ID
```

But I still don't know how to write this correctly...
The select distinct only returns some of the data.
I need select * to be able to use the rest of the data.
So if I join the unique with * on ID the result should be all the data that is not a dupe. In theory I think this is correct.

So how do I fit my theory with my original code?

```
<?php 
$searchresults=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' order by Artist limit 100");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($searchresults) > 0) {
              while($descri=mysqli_fetch_object($searchresults)) { ?>
                <div class="reslt">
                  <h3 id="results">
                    <?php
                      echo str_ireplace($searchterm, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchterm."</span>", $descri->Artist);
                      echo " - ";
                      echo str_ireplace($searchterm, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchterm."</span>", $descri->Title);
                    ?>
                  </h3>
                  <p class="Description">
                    <?php
                      echo $descri->Brand; echo " - ";
                      echo str_ireplace($searchterm, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchterm."</span>", $descri->Disc);
                      echo " - "; echo $descri->Track;
                    ?>
                  </p>
                  <hr>
                </div>
              <?php } }?>
```